# IF with ternary operator - Verilog

Tags: verilog

I am trying to write a program in Verilog that should "move" a light LED on an array of LEDs. With a button the light should move to the left, with another one it should move to the right. This is my code:

```
module led_shift(UP, DOWN, RES, CLK, LED);
input UP, DOWN, RES, CLK;
output reg [7:0] LED;
reg [7:0] STATE;

always@(negedge DOWN or negedge UP or negedge RES)
begin
    if(!RES)
    begin
        STATE <= 8'b00010000;
    end
    else
    begin
        STATE <= UP ? STATE>>1 : STATE<<1;
    end
end

always @ (posedge CLK)
begin
    LED <= STATE;
end
endmodule
```

The problem is in **STATE <= UP ? STATE>>1 : STATE<<1;** and the error the following:

Error (10200): Verilog HDL Conditional Statement error at led_shift.v(34): cannot match operand(s) in the condition to the corresponding edges in the enclosing event control of the always construct

I tried to modify the code without using that kind of if:

```
always@(negedge DOWN or negedge UP or negedge RES)
begin
    if(!RES)
        STATE <= 8'b00010000;
    else
    begin   
        if(!DOWN)
            STATE <= STATE<<1;
        else
        begin
            if(!UP)
                STATE <= STATE>>1;
            else
                STATE <= STATE;
        end
    end
end
```

It compiles, but does not work: the LED "moves" only to the left, when I press the other button all LEDs shut down. Probably there is a problem in my code, but I cannot understand why my first code does not compile at all. 
Thank you for any help!

harrym

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear for the synthesizer to know how to control `STATE` with the 3 asynchronous control signals.

Most likely your your synthesizer is trying to map `STATE` to a D flip flop with asynchronous active low set and reset. For example it might be trying to synthesize to something like:

```
dff state_0_(.Q(STATE[0], .CLK(DOWN), .SET_N(UP), .RST_N(RES(, .D(/*...*/));
```

In a real flop with asynchronous set and reset, the default should be consent and would explain the error in your first code. In your second attempt, `UP` becomes part of the combination logic cloud along with `DOWN`. `DOWN` is also being used as a clock. Since `UP` is not a clock, shifting continuously happens while `UP` is low, completely shifting the on bit out instantly. Another error for the second case would actually be more appropriate.

For the synthesizer to do a better job, you first need to synchronize your asynchronous control signals. Use the same technique as CDC (clock domain crossing; A paper by Cliff Cummings goes into detains [here](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2008Boston_CDC.pdf)). A basic example:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
    pre_sync_DOWN <= DOWN;
    sync_DOWN <= pre_sync_DOWN;
end
```

Now that the controls signals are synchronized, make `STATE` the output of your combination logic. Example:

```
always @* begin
    if(!sync_RES)
        STATE = 8'b00010000;
    else
      case({sync_UP,sync_DOWN})
        2'b01  : STATE = LED>>1;
        2'b10  : STATE = LED<<1;
        default: STATE = LED;
      endcase
end
```

With everything running on one clock domain and explicitly defined combination logic, the synthesizer can construct equivalent logic using flops and basic gates.

---

FYI:

To shift only on a `negedge` event you need to keep the last sync value and check for the high to low transition. Remember to swap `sync_` with `do_` in the combination logic that drives `STATE`.

```
always @(posedge clk)
    keep_DOWN <= sync_DOWN;
always @*
    do_DOWN = (keep_DOWN && !sync_DOWN);
```

Comment: Thanks! Perfect answer. The project still does not work (every button I press, the LED shuts down, maybe the shift is too fast), but at least it compiles. I will check the signal in a simulation. What I do not get is why, in my second code,  shifting continuosly happens when UP is low. It should only shift when one of the signal in the sensitivity list goes down and when UP is low, should not?

Comment: Try drawing or writing your code with gates, with `STATE` being the output of a negedge DFF with an asynchronous active low set and reset. `UP` will be level sensitive (not edge sensitive) so the high bit will be shifted out instantly (only potential slow down is peristaltic delay).

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of edge detection. It will shift once per negedge event.